# How to calculate the cardinality of the intersection of three sets?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I have a universe (or total number of people polled who are distributed amongst these sets) of $151$ persons.

These sets correspond to which TV shows they watch (i.e., each set represents one TV show):
$$n(A) = 68; n(B) = 61; n(C) = 52.$$

Also provided are the cardinalities of their paired intersections:
$$n(A\cap B) = 16; n(A\cap C) = 25; n(B\cap C) = 19.$$

Given this information how do I go about determining the cardinality of the intersection of all three sets? Step by step, formulaic, with basic explanations where appropriate, please. External references are appreciated but I need to see a solution in context. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Are we guaranteed that each of the universe of $151$ people watches at least one show? If not, this problem has $8$ unknowns ($3$ sets gives $2^3$ possibilities) and only $7$ pieces of information. This is not enough to determine a unique answer. If there are no people who watch no shows, this addes the necessary $8$th piece of information.

Comment: It is impossible that all $151$ people watch at least one show.  If that were true, we would have $|A\cup B\cup C| = 151$, and PIE gives us $|A\cap B\cap C| = 30 > |A\cap B|$.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, $n(A\cap B\cap C)\le n(A\cap B)=16$. Just draw a Venn diagram and observe that indeed every value $0\ldots 16$ is possible. (The principle of inclusion and exclusion would only give a much weaker bound in this specific example!)
To be explicit, with $0\le k\le 16$, we can let
$$\begin{align}
n(A\cap B\cap C)&=k\\
n(A\cap B\cap \bar C)&=16-k\\
n(A\cap \bar B\cap C)&=25-k\\
n(A\cap \bar B\cap \bar C)&=27+k\\
n(\bar A\cap B\cap C)&=19-k\\
n(\bar A\cap B\cap \bar C)&=26+k\\
n(\bar A\cap \bar B\cap C)&=8+k\\
n(\bar A\cap \bar B\cap \bar C)&=30-k\\
\end{align} $$
For example, you will verify that this makes $n(C)=n(\bar A\cap \bar B\cap C)+n(\bar A\cap  B\cap C)+n( A\cap \bar B\cap C)+n( A\cap  B\cap C) = (8+k)+(19-k)+(25-k)+k = 52 $ as required.
Especially, we find out that at least $14$ people dont watch any of the shows (for $30-k\ge 14$).

Comment: Just to be clear, the issue here is that there there are some people (as you say, at least 14) who do not watch any of the shows $A$, $B$, and $C$.  So $|A\cup B\cup C|$ is unknown.  If we knew this value, _then_ we could use the principle of inclusion/exclusion to find $|A\cap B\cap C|$.

Comment: Yes, starting only from the original info, we can only input $n(A\cup B\cup C)\le 151$ into the i/e principle, which gives $n(A\cap B\cap C)\le 30$.

Comment: how is _n_(A∩B¯∩C¯) = 27 + k?

Comment: This makes $n(A)=n(A\cap \bar B \cap \bar C) + n(A\cap \bar B \cap C)+n(A\cap B \cap \bar C)+n(A\cap  B \cap C) = (27+k)+(25-k)+(16-k)+k = 68$ as required.